# Why my JPanel components get autofilled?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am designing the GUI of my application and I am having some problems with the communication between my Swing Components.
I have a class MainGUI where on user click a new JDialog object must be created and show up. The Dialog pops up as I want to ,but it always shows me the previous values which have been entered the last time I visited it. How to prevent that and what is the reason for that behaviour ? I suppose that I am doing something wrong with the openActorDialog() function.

```
public class MainGUI extends JPanel {
private ArrayList<Actor> actorList = new ArrayList<Actor>();
private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
private JButton openDialogeBtn = new JButton("Open Dialog");
private String description;
// here my main gui has a reference to the JDialog and to the
// MyDialogPanel which is displayed in the JDialog

private JDialog dialog;

public MainGUI() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    add(openDialogeBtn);
    field.setEditable(false);
    field.setFocusable(false);

    add(field);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenu mnNew = new JMenu("New");
    mnFile.add(mnNew);

    JMenuItem mntmSystem = new JMenuItem("system");
    mnNew.add(mntmSystem);

    JMenuItem mntmUseCase = new JMenuItem("use case");
    mnNew.add(mntmUseCase);

    JMenuItem mntmActor = new JMenuItem("actor");
    mnNew.add(mntmActor);

    JTree tree = new JTree();
    add(tree, BorderLayout.WEST);

    /*
     * Here we set the actions to be performed when the user interacts
     */

    mntmActor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            openActorDialog();
        }
    });

}

private void openActorDialog() {
    //Creation of the JDialog
    CreateActorDialog createActorPanel = new CreateActorDialog();
    if (dialog == null) {
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        if (win != null) {
            dialog = new JDialog(win, "Create an actor", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            dialog.getContentPane().add(createActorPanel);
            dialog.setSize(500, 360);
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        }
    }
    dialog.setVisible(true); // here the modal dialog takes over

    // this line starts *after* the modal dialog has been disposed
    // **** here's the key where I get the String from JTextField in the GUI
    // held
    // by the JDialog and put it into this GUI's JTextField.

    Actor a = new Actor(createActorPanel.getActorNameFromDialog(),
            createActorPanel.getActorDescriptionFromDialog());
    field.setText(createActorPanel.getActorNameFromDialog());
    actorList.add(a);
    System.out.println("It is written:" + createActorPanel.getActorDescriptionFromDialog());
    for (Actor actor : actorList) {
        System.out.println(actor.name + " with description :" + actor.description); // Will
                                                                                    // invoke
                                                                                    // override
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What's `CreateActorDialog` doing?

Comment: CreateActorDialog is a class that extends JPanel and has some textfields where the user sets the values.

Comment: `dialog`, once created, will always be the same, you never replace the instance of `createActorPanel` on the dialog, so it will contain the old values from the last time it was shown.  Either replace the component (making sure to remove the old one) or have some kind of "reset" method which resets its values

Comment: I just set the dialog to null , as huellif  suggested and now it is working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set dialog to null again after you used it or before you use it, otherwise you will see the old dialog.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice this...now it is working properly !